# How do I change default database on Login and pass all requests to that database for that session in Laravel application?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm working on a method where based on financial year the default database has to change on login.
For example: If financial year is 2022-2023 then default database should change to "database1", if year is 2023-2024 then default has to change to "database2".

I'm working on a module where on login the default database has to change to another one and use it for the rest of the session. How do I make this happen? I tried the already existing one and it only works for single request. I want all the request to use the current database.

Comment: I would seriously question a design which needs a new database every year. What caused that decision?

Comment: Because the user adds and uses fresh steam of data every year and they also should be able to use the previous year's data separately which should not collide with the current year's data.

Comment: Well the simple way to solve that is to record the date against every relevant row of data, and then in your front-end or your queries, you can select only the current year's data as the default (but of course then you have the freedom to change it if you need to search or report across multiple years). Archiving everything and starting again should only be done if you're running into serious performance problems - and even then, there are probably better fixes to try first.

Comment: Do you think all the big accountancy, banking and financial software systems start again with a new database every year? Of course they don't...that would be crazy in terms or risk and workload, and clearly makes reporting and auditing etc 10 times harder. And also they know how to do things like use a WHERE clause to restrict queries by date so they only get current data in the front-end when that's required. Seriously, your design is badly flawed - please think again, as it will just cause you more and more headaches until you resolve it. See also the [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out the error. I've updated the design to use the same database every year.